# How do I keep yarn workspaces dependencies in sync

Tags: yarnpkg, package.json, yarn-workspaces

Let's say I have multiple packages in my `yarn workspaces`.

```
@mycompany/utils
@mycompany/app
@mycompany/serv
```

Let's say each of these packages has a `dependency` on `lodash`. I want to make sure that they all have the same `lodash` version.

Is there a way to do that in each of the package.json?

Comment: If this is still on the agenda, how about adding lodash to the root package.json: `yarn add lodash -W`?

Comment: Yea I did that at first and realized that adding it into the root package.json isn't really a great solution because you wouldn't be able to tell which package has which dependencies later on ):

Comment: I am currently facing a similar problem. If you have it solved, how did you solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately.. I haven't solved it ):

Comment: One thing I wanted to look into was maybe using https://dependabot.com/ since it got acquired by Github and is now free so that could help keep all dependencies up to date

Comment: May it help, we are switching to real monorepo architecture. We use Yarn workspaces and Lerna. With `lerna add lodash`, it adds lodash to all packages. The only trick I found to guarantee that dependencies have the same version everywhere is to remove it (Maybe `lerna exec -- yarn remove lodash) and re-add it `lerna add lodash@x.y.z`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `syncpack` to force all sub-packages in a monorepo uses the same version of each dependency.

Install in the root package.json:

```
yarn add --dev -W syncpack
```

Run (Recommnded: Run on every commit using husky):

```
syncpack list-mismatches
```

More info: https://github.com/JamieMason/syncpack