# How in Yarn 2 do I share common dependencies in workspaces?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

Mostly the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54498006/206466), but for yarn 2. I put my shared dependencies at the top of the hierarchy. I believe I'm not using PnP currently.

`.yarnrc.yaml`

```yml
nodeLinker: node-modules
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-2.2.2.cjs
```

at the very top level I have `typescript` installed (but I presume this could be any module with a binary) down in one of my "workspaces" I want to call `tsc`, however it's `command not found: tsc` I've also noticed some warnings like. `graph@workspace:app-lib/graph/packages/app doesn't provide jest@>=24 <25 requested by ts-jest@npm:24.3.0` which is provided in the parent of app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/qa#how-to-share-scripts-between-workspaces

> Little-known Yarn feature: any script with a colon in its name (build:foo) can be called from any workspace. Another little-known feature: $INIT_CWD will always point to the directory running the script. Put together, you can write scripts that can be reused this way:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "g:tsc": "cd $INIT_CWD && tsc"
  }
}
```

> Then, from any workspace that contains its own tsconfig.json, you'll be able to call TypeScript:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn g:tsc"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-T,--top-level` flag with `yarn run`. It will look for root level dependencies.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "yarn run -T tsc"
  }
}
```

https://yarnpkg.com/cli/run